# Constructing Binary Tree from given preorder and postorder by using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree, preorder, postorder

I am making binary tree form given pre and post order.

**pre-order: "vwbcyznamlp"**

**Post-order: "cbznywmplav"**

**LOGIC FOR THIS PURPOSE**

```
V W B C Y Z N A M L P
C B Z N Y W M P L A V
```

First, note the root is V because it's both first in the preorder and last in the postorder:

```
V W B C Y Z N A M L P
  C B Z N Y W M P L A V
```

Then look at W and A, they are, respectively, they are first left child and the last right child of the root. A in the preorder marks the place where the traversal transitions from the left subtree of the root to the right subtree of the root. W in the postorder marks the same place. Note that that when you split the traversals, A and W are adjacent positions:

```
V W B C Y Z N    A M L P
  C B Z N Y W    M P L A V
```

Now you are left to solve the same problem for the sequences:

```
W B C Y Z N    
C B Z N Y W
```

and

```
A M L P
M P L A
```

For example, the next step for the first sequence would be:

```
W B C    Y Z N    
  C B    Z N Y W
```

I am making tree through recursion but some conditions in recursion I didn't recognize. Therefore when I traverse this tree through preoder then the answer was not correct.

After making tree through recursion the answer was

**pre-order: "vwbccyznaml"**

The code I did is here

First I made Tree Struct

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  #include <stack>
  using namespace std;
  struct TreeNode
  {
  public:
   string enteredData;
   struct TreeNode *left;
   struct TreeNode *right;
   struct TreeNode* newNode(string data)
    {
     struct TreeNode* temp = new TreeNode();
     temp->enteredData = data;
     temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
     return temp;
   }
  };
  struct TreeNode* Buildingtree(string preorder, string postorder);
```

Additional Functions

```
//for returning tree
struct TreeNode *constructTree(string preorder, string postorder)
{
int preIndex = 0;
return Buildingtree(preorder, postorder);
}


//for pre-order traversal
void printPreorder(struct TreeNode* node)
{
if (node == NULL)
    return;
cout << node->enteredData << " ";
printPreorder(node->left);
printPreorder(node->right);
}


//for building tree from given preorder and postorder
struct TreeNode* Buildingtree(string preorder, string postorder)
{
string newPreoderForFunction = "";
string newPostoderForFunction = "";
struct TreeNode* root = new TreeNode();
string rightpreorder;
string rightpostorder;
static stack<string> u;
int indexForPreOder = 1;
int indexForPostOrder = postorder.length() - 2;
if (indexForPostOrder <= -1)
{
    string g;
    if (preorder != "")
        g.assign(1, preorder[0]);
    else
        g.assign(1, postorder[0]);
    root = root->newNode(g);
    return root;
 }
 else
 {
    string findingCharFromPreorder;
    findingCharFromPreorder.assign(1, preorder[indexForPreOder]);
    string findingCharFromPostorder;
    findingCharFromPostorder.assign(1, postorder[indexForPostOrder]);
    size_t found;
    string h = "";
    if (preorder != "")
        h.assign(1, preorder[0]);
    else if (postorder != "")
        h.assign(1, postorder[0]);
    root = root->newNode(h);
    if ((found = preorder.find(findingCharFromPostorder)) != string::npos)
    {
        newPreoderForFunction = preorder.substr(1, found - 1);
        rightpreorder = preorder.substr(found, preorder.length() - 1);
        u.push(rightpreorder);
    }
    if ((found = postorder.find(findingCharFromPreorder)) != string::npos)
    {

        newPostoderForFunction = postorder.substr(0, found + 1);

        rightpostorder = postorder.substr(found + 1, indexForPostOrder);

        if (rightpostorder.length() > 1)
            rightpostorder.erase(rightpostorder.length() - 1);
        u.push(rightpostorder);

    }
  }
  root->left = Buildingtree(newPreoderForFunction, newPostoderForFunction);
  string a;
  string b;
  a = u.top();
  u.pop();
  b = u.top();
  u.pop();
  root->right = Buildingtree(b, a);
  return root;
}
```

Main function

```
int main()
{
string a1 = "vwbcyznamlp";
string a2 = "cbznywmplav";
struct TreeNode *root = constructTree(a1,a2);
printPreorder(root);
cout << endl;
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: It's hard work debugging recursive functions, but sometimes that's what needs to be done. Use a debugger and step through the code line by line until you find something that doesn't work as expected. I suggest you start with a smaller input set, to make the process easier. Plenty of descriptive comments, perhaps trying to break things into smaller units (functions), and [rubber duck debugging](http://www.rubberduckdebugging.com/) also helps.

Comment: Can you suggest any books which made my understanding in recursion and trees easier.